# Form::model+checkbox na view edit

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-eloquent

Estou usando `form::model` para edição de dados. Funciona corretamente mas, os checkbox retornam vazios. Como faço para retornar os que estão salvos no bd?

Quero que eles mostrem os que estão cadastrados. Por exemplo: no cadastro do curso marquei Manhã e tarde, então na edição tem que retornar os dois marcados e mais um vazio, no caso Noite.

> [v] Manhã [v] Tarde [ ] Noite

**View edit:**

```
{{ Form::model($curso, array('method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('painel.cursos.update', $curso->id))) }}
    <label>{{ Form::checkbox( 'turnos[0]', 'Manhã') }} Manhã</label>
    <label>{{ Form::checkbox( 'turnos[1]', 'Tarde') }} Tarde</label>
    <label>{{ Form::checkbox( 'turnos[2]', 'Noite') }} Noite</label>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Assim retornam vazios.

Já desta outra forma retomam somente os salvos no bd:

```
<?php $course = explode(",", $curso->turno);?>
@foreach ($course as $c)
    <label>{{ Form::checkbox('turnos[]', $c, true) }} {{$c}}</label>
@endforeach
```

Não estou sabendo como fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente consegui resolver.

```
<?php $array = explode(",", $curso->turno);?>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="turnos[]" value="Manhã" <?php if(in_array('Manhã', $array)) echo( 'checked = "checked"'); ?>/> Manhã</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="turnos[]" value="Tarde" <?php if(in_array('Tarde', $array)) echo( 'checked = "checked"'); ?>/> Tarde</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="turnos[]" value="Noite" <?php if(in_array('Noite', $array)) echo( 'checked = "checked"'); ?>/> Noite</label>
```